# React.js - problem of not appearing Background

Tags: reactjs

My background image is not appearing on the output. It only doesn't work on the Contact Us page, while on other pages it's working. The div is showing the correct style in the console.

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: "url(images/iletisim.jpeg)"}}>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kOKm.png) is a screenshot of the application

Comment: Make sure you are not storing image in public directory...nowadays you have to put static files in src directory itself.

Comment: add some height and width to the div and make sure the path to image is valid.

Comment: Im sure, image file and .jpegs in src file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check the image is your right directory.

```
import image from "../../images/iletisim.jpeg";
.
.
.

<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image})`}}>
.
.
.

</div>
```

Comment: image is in right directory ı will share with you Git Hub link can u control it please

Comment: https://github.com/mehmetbatuhanyilmaz/patika-frontend-projects

Comment: Its on src>pages>contactus

Comment: I just check ur code you were on the wrong path. First import image like below **import image from "../../images/iletisim.jpeg";** and then recalled it by using like this      **<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}>**

Comment: If you don't understand the above comment check above previous I was edited

Comment: I understand it, thank you so so so much :)